# How to change a specific date value in an index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the last index value in a dateframe to another date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_1 = datetime(2021,5,31,0,0)
date_2 = datetime(2021,6,30,0,0)
df=pd.DataFrame(index={date_1,date_2},data = {1,2},columns={'X'})
```

I also have a variable for the date I want, which is of type datetime

```
last_dt = datetime(2021, 6, 24, 0, 0)
```

When I try and join the two I get an error message "Index does not support mutable operations"

```
df.index[-1]=last_dt
```

While the index is also of the type datetime, the last value (df.index[-1]) is of type timestamp.

```
type(df.index[-1])
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

I am guessing this mismatch is what is causing the error but not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.Index` objects don't support item assignment directly, so one way is to construct the new index manually and assign it back:

```
# we put the values till last one as is and add `last_dt` at last
df.index = [*df.index[:-1], last_dt]
```

or you can manipulate the underlying array:

```
df.index.array[-1] = last_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way:

```
df.set_axis((df.index[:-1].union([last_dt],sort=False)),axis=0)
```